# does version of ZF2 matter in enabling memcache?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, memcached

actually , i already enabled the memcache on a projet zf2 version 2.2.0 and when trying to do the same on a new project zf2 with version 2.5.1; i can't.

Here is what i tried ( module.config.php ) :

```
     'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
            $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
            $memcache = new \Memcache();
            $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
            $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
            return $cache;
            },
        ),

    ),

    // Doctrine config
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    /***** enabling the memcache ****/
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'metadata_cache'    => 'memcache',
            'query_cache'       => 'memcache',
            'result_cache'      => 'memcache',
        )
    ),
    /**** end ****/
    'cache' => array(
        'memcache' => array(
            'instance' => 'doctrine.cache.mycache',
        ),
    ),
),
```

What i missed up ?

Thanks.

Comment: How does the error message look like?

Comment: Memcachee has one 'e' too many

Comment: @tookie009 there is no message , just i can't see the data i try to store in cache.

Comment: @JannesBotis sorry about that , i just add it trying to get some errors message .

Answer (score 0):

have you activate memcache as session container in web-server settings?

For apache:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```

**EDIT**

Are you sure, you are using memcache and no memcache**d**?

Comment: where add this ?

Comment: check your phpinfo(), if memcached is activated.